# Music doesnot stop after pressing backkey

Tags: android

I have an activity A which invokes Activity B on Button Click,and a Button click on Activity B invokes Class C. When button is clicked in Activity B , B calls a static method in Class C which passes its reference as one of the argument to method in C and other argument is path to the sound file that needs to be played. Once control reaches class C , Audio is played. But when Backkey is pressed Audio doesnot stop it continuous to play. How can I make the Audio to stop when BackKey is pressed. More over when Backkey is pressed control is coming to Activity A instead of Activity B. Can any one help me in solving this issue?

class activityA extends Activity  
{
   startIntent(ActivityB)  on ButtonPress 
}

class ActivityB extends Activity 
{
   classc.playAudio(ActivityB.this,audiopath); 
}

class c 
{
  playAudio(Activity a, audiopath) 
   {
    sound code to play audio is done here. 
    } 
}

Comment: `which passes its reference` dear god don't do that

Answer (score 0):

Use this in C activity , trap back key when going back from activity C

@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            //stop your music here 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

Comment: but c is not an Activity. It is normal java class. So, how to override onKeyDown() in this class?

Comment: Don't track the back key.  You will miss things like home.  Instead do this in either onPause() or onStop() as desired.

Comment: Well this could be alternative better strategy.. Thanks hackbod